# Why golang shifting operator takes precedence over addition?

Tags: go, operator-precedence

```
java:  System.out.println(1 + (9 - 1) >> 1);  // OUPUT: "4"
```

```
golang: fmt.Println(1 + (9 - 1) >> 1) // OUPUT: "5"
```

Go: https://kuree.gitbooks.io/the-go-programming-language-report/content/31/text.html

Java: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

Python: http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html

C/C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

It seems only golang >> is taking precedence over +? But why?

Comment: Because the people who designed Go liked it more that way :)

Comment: I don't understand why some members closed this question as _primarily opinion-based_. And I strongly disagree with @rici comment. If there is anything you **never** do when designing a programming language, especially within a company like Google, it's picking choices out of "opinions". I'm quite sure they started a RFC and seriously debated this design before making it, for well-argued reasons. Moreover, even if this question format is quite bad, the matter in itself is a very interesting one regarding SO standards.

Answer (score 4):

This is a difference in language philosophy and usability.
Go views the operations as multiplication/division by powers of 2, a functional view.  The other languages regard it as a bit-based operators, which they class next to Boolean operators.  This is based more on a sense of common data type/view.

Comment: did not get you. Can you share some link to explore further?